# Docker-compose SystaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn Docker-compose by following [this simple example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount), however after I add the "volumes: .:/code: to my docker-compose file, I got a `SystaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.
It works well if I don't add the volumes. Am I missing something? Thanks!

EDIT: here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: Show us your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: I just added to the original message!

Answer (score 0):

YAML is super fussy about indentation. Make sure that each line of indentation is the same number of spaces (generally 2 or 4). In your case, it looks like you are using two spaces. The following lines:

```
ports:
 - "5000:5000"
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

Look like they only have one space of indentation. In other words, they should be:

```
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  - .:/code
```